# how to write a script to read double quotes in powershell

Tags: json, powershell

Hi every one i am trying to read a string which is enclosed in double quotes within a file e.g "cars" :
I am using this command but unable to read it may be I am not using the right format to read the quotes

```
$houseid = $json |Get-Content |Select-String -pattern ""houseid":"| measure | select -exp count

write-host "houseid = " $houseid
```

I am reading the file from json file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap you pattern in single quotes when it contains quotes. Although it's not necessary, you should add `-SimpleMatch` to specify that it is a normal string-pattern and not regex.

```
#Valid sample
'"houseid":myjsonvalue' | Select-String -Pattern '"houseid":' -SimpleMatch | measure | select -ExpandProperty count    
1

#Invalid sample
'houseid:myjsonvalue' | Select-String -Pattern '"houseid":' -SimpleMatch | measure | select -ExpandProperty count
0
```